# VBA Excel: Prevent Excel to change data as date after changing all cells to uppercase

Tags: excel, date, uppercase, vba

I have the following code to capitalize all data in two specified ranges and then run some comparing code.
The issue is once it runs the capitalize code cells that contain something like `1-2` gets changed to `2-Jan`. I cannot apply `.NumberFormat = "@"` to the entire worksheet or that specific column because I am making the sheet dynamic and this data won't always be in the same column. Anyone know how to take care of this problem?

```
Dim rangeToUse As Range, singleArea As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, rng As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim I As Integer, J As Integer

'Set two range selections
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select First Range", "Obtain 1st Range Object", Type:=8)
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Second Range", "Obtain 2nd Range Object", Type:=8)
Set MultiRange = Union(rng, rng2)
MultiRange.Select

Set rangeToUse = Selection
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

'Capitalizes all cells in selected range
'Turn off screen updating to increase performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Worksheets("Phase 3 xwire").Range(rangeToUse).NumberFormat = "@"

   'Convert all constants and text values to proper case
   For Each LCell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
      LCell.Formula = UCase(LCell.Formula)
      Calculate
   Next

If Selection.Areas.Count <= 1 Then
      MsgBox "Please select more than one area."
    Else
        rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        For Each singleArea In rangeToUse.Areas
            singleArea.BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
        Next singleArea
        'Areas.count - 1 will avoid trying to compare
        ' Area(count) to the non-existent area(count+1)
        For I = 1 To rangeToUse.Areas.Count - 1
            For Each cell1 In rangeToUse.Areas(I)
                'I+1 gets you the NEXT area
                Set cell2 = rangeToUse.Areas(I + 1).Cells(cell1.Row - 1, cell1.Column - 1)
                 If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then
                 GoTo Done
                 Else
                    If cell1.Value <> cell2.Value Then
                        cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                        cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                    End If
                 End If
            Next cell1
        Next I
Done:
End If
'Turn screen updating back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are keeping the Input Boxes you could add this line of code after your `MultiRange.Select` command

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Thank you @JerryT, I have one more question for you regarding this same code.
I am also trying to strip out all spaces and I'm using this:

`'Remove unnecessary spaces
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False`

This is also causing the formating to do the same thing as the Capitalizing I was doing. Any idea how to resolve this issue?